# Visual Studio 2010 - Post Build Event triggers but description text not shown in Output window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Using VS2010, I've got a Post Build Event setup on my project and the action itself is triggering correctly however the text I entered in the Description field when setting up the Post Build Event is not being displayed in the Output window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Care to post the MSBuild script? Open up your project file in a text editor and the relevant code will be towards the bottom of the script in it's own <Target>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the output level needs to be increased. Try bumping up the value found in:

*VS2010 -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity*

It could also be the message level in your script, but we'd need to see that script to be sure.

Comment: Good call.  Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run.

MSBuild Project Build Output Verbosity defaults to Minimal on my setup, the Post Build Event Description doesn't show unless it's bumped up to at least Normal.

Comment: Glad it helped. FWIW, depending on how the script works, you might be able to bump the output level from the script itself so you don't need to muck around with the VS verbosity level (so it will work on other boxes). For example, if it's an MSBuild Message task, you could bump the importance to 'High', see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yy0yx8d.aspx